# How to remove space above/beside tmux window?

Tags: bash, tmux, spacing

I am using tmux in bash on my MacBook Pro. Inside tmux, there is some spacing above/beside the tmux statusbar and shell that I'd like to get rid of.

[image: tmux spacing]

I zoomed in a bit further for better visibility:

[image: tmux spacing]

As you can see, there are 2px spacing top of the status bar and 5px spacing left of the entire shell. Is there an option I can specify in my .tmux.conf to get rid of this?

Comment: This might be because your window is not an exact multiple of the font size. If you shrink the window height by 2 or 3 pixels does the space go away?

Comment: I can only shrink my window height in discrete steps, each of which is equal to the height of one line, so the spacing does not change unfortunately.

Comment: Changing my font size does actually make the spacing go away, but only the one above the status bar, not on the sides. Also, the font size is then either way too big or too small to be useful.

Comment: It is probably a feature of your terminal emulator. Which one are you using? It might have some padding options? I don't know MacOS enough to help. You might compare with another terminal like `xterm`.

Comment: I'm using the default/preinstalled Terminal. I just tried it out with iTerm2, the problem persists, though.

Comment: You could try asking on sister site for MacOS [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). For example this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366119/mac-terminal-padding) seems to be the opposite to yours.

Comment: I will do that, thank you for your help :)